# python delete file if name begins with 'xyz'

Tags: python

I have several files in my folder `xyz_driver`, `xyz_tool`, `xyz_mac`, `aaa_driver`, `aaa_tool`, `aaa_mac`

If I were to do

```
for filename in glob.glob('xyz_driver'):
    os.remove(filename)
```

it works.

But how do I delete all files **only** if the name begins with `xyz`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) supports wildcard pattern matching:

```
for filename in glob.glob('xyz*'):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: Simple, effective, and fast! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename[:3] == 'xyz':
        os.remove(filename)
```

EDIT:

As zondo implied, this might give you an error if you use python2.x, the correct syntax is then `os.listdir(path)` where path is the folder in which you wish to list content.

Answer (score 1):

```
for filename in glob.glob('xyz_driver'):
  if filename.startswith('xyz'):
    os.remove(filename)
```